# permit root login red hat

Tags: linux, ssh, root

I'm bit confused because I can't perform such an easy thing as permitting root login to the server (I'm using redhat). I changed `PermitRootLogin` from `no` to `yes` on the server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and then restarted `sshd` service but that didn't give me what I want. Do anybody knows any other ways of how root login via ssh can be permitted?

Thanks in advance!

Error message is:

```
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 pam_root_login[29703]: pam_root_login user name:root
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 pam_root_login[29703]: Customer-Root retval:0, value:disabled
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 pam_root_login[29703]: pam_root_login: Root access NOT allowed
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 pam_asg[29703]: Login for [root] - rhost[192.168.114.62],tty[ssh]
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 pam_asg[29703]: Login root not an ASG login
May 30 21:25:20 mngmsg39 sshd[29703]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=192.168.114.62  user=root
```

Comment: What error did it give you? I won't even go into the reasons why its a bad idea, but what error did it give you?

Comment: @NickW, could you please tell where can I look at the error? The thing is that I can log in as root via `su`, but unable via `ssh`.

Comment: Well, you should have errors for ssh in `/var/log/secure` but otherwise, they may be in `/var/log/messages`

Comment: Where did your set `PermitRootLogin`? Please include all details, which files did you edit? It is MUCH MUCH better to login as a normal user and then switch to root if you have to.

Comment: @NickW, I look into the logs and it seems that PAM restricts me from logging in as root. Are there any guidelines of how it can be overcome?

Comment: @terdon, `PermitRootLogin` was set in the sshd_config, as usual. I know, that this is better and more secure, but it is a development environment, not a production one.

Comment: @mr.nothing I added the info to your question. In the future always include details, you would be surprised how many people have edited their _local_ `ssh_config` for example. The more details you include the likelier it is we'll be able to help. What error message do you get when you try to log in as `root`?

Comment: Have a look in the /etc/pam.d/sshd file..

Comment: @terdon I added error message to the post. Thanks!

Comment: change "UsePAM yes" to "UsePAM no"

Comment: @darkphader wouldn't that make password logins slightly difficult?

Comment: Not in my experience, in fact PAM auth can bypass such settings as AllowUsers, PermitRootLogin, etc.

Comment: I was suggesting that the piece of software that handles the password login is PAM, but I suppose it may actually be something else.. still think he should look into the /etc/pam/ssh[x] file, as that's where redhat says you can disable root logins for ssh, and many other pieces of software.. http://www.centos.org/docs/4/4.5/Security_Guide/s2-wstation-privileges-noroot.html towards the bottom.

Comment: it really looks to me like you are trying to revitalize an Avaya Voice system of some kind. Am I right ? If yes, would you like to share your experience ?